# Firebase.h file not found with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I am trying to add Firebase into my project. I just added below pods into my Xcode project.

```
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

After installing podfile, I try to import firebase into my project. But it gives me an error that **Firebase.h is not found.**

[image: na]

Above issue will occur when I uncheck the `Run script only when installing` from `[CP] Check pods Manifest.lock`. After that I will installed pod using `pod install`. And then issue will occur.

Error which I got after uncheck the checkbox:

```
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

Comment: Can not reproduce, try upload a sample project.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to upload the whole project l

Comment: Build the project.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien same issue dude

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982440/firebase-h-file-not-found-with-cocoapods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issues on my project,

I wrote manually link the project and its libraries to solve the problem I followed this link steps it worked 
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/installation/ios.md

Also, you must check you link binary with libraries on your Xcode project.

Another solution you can delete all pod depend on libs then you `pod init` 
add manual pod libs after `pod install`

Comment: I updated any question and put steps through which error will occur.

Comment: Please delete lock file and again pod insall

Answer (score 0):

Deintegrate pod then reinstall it.

Deintegrate:- pod deintegrate

install:- pod install

This works for me.